# How tu use a global variable as a variable in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I don't know if this is the right title for this question but this is my example:

```js
var myvar = [];
var othervar = [];
var somevar = [];

function testing(type) {
 window[type].push('some value');
 console.log(type);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testing('myvar')">press here</button>
<button onclick="testing('othervar')">press here</button>
<button onclick="testing('somevar')">press here</button>
```

this function should push some value to the global variable indicated as its argument but nothing happens. I also tried `type.push('some value');` but it didn't work either. What is the right syntax?

Comment: `type` references the argument, not the outer variable - reference `window[type]` instead, just like you're doing when pushing

Comment: The function should change the values in `myvar`, or whatever the variable it is in the argument. Thats the whole point.

Comment: reference window[type]? You mean console.log(window[type])?

Comment: if you solved please also add an answer